# How to extract the last names from text file using nltk in python

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

inputfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
String= inputfile.read()


def last_name(resume_text):
  tokenized_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(resume_text)
  a_list=[]
  for sentence in tokenized_sentences:
      a_list=(sentence.split())
      s1=a_list[1:]
      sentence1=''.join(s1)
      tokenized_sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence1)
      for sentence in tokenized_sentences:
          for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence), tagset='universal')):
            if hasattr(chunk, 'label') and chunk.label() == 'PERSON':
              chunk = chunk[0]
            (name, tag) = chunk
            if tag == 'NOUN':
              return name
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lastname= last_name(String)
print(lastname)
```

I want to extract the last name from a resume. It returns the first name correctly but the second name is wrong.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your input file?

Comment: JAY PRATAP PANDEY
Mobile: +91111111111
Email: pratappandey7@gmail.com
Location: New Delhi, Delhi, India

OBJECTIVE:
To secure a promising position that offers both a challenge and a good opportunity for growth.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571213/extract-the-name-of-candidate-from-text-file-using-python-and-nltk